# How to split and join a text considering special characters?

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

My Input is this: `'z<*zj'`;
I am looking a Output as : `j<*zz`;

here in this string, special characters not changed in position. But the letters arranged reversed  alphabets. I am trying to get the output, but not works.

any one help me with shortest and correct way to get this?

my try:

```
const  Reverser = (str)  =>{
  return str.replace(/[a-zA-Z]+/gm,  (item) => {
    return item.split('')[0].split('')
  });
}

const result = Reverser('z<*zj');
console.log(result);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I really think we need more examples, if we should make a more general regex that works .

Comment: Not clear. Do you expect exactly one alpha, non-alpha, alpha pattern, or are there more repetitions? A few example input and expected output would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if I understand you correctly.
But I think you want to sort only the letters without changing non-letters?

Here is my approach:

```
const Reverser = (str) => {

  // create sorted array of all letters found
  // first remove all non-letters, then split into array
  // then sort in reverse so that we can use fast .pop() instead of slow .shift()

  let letters = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]+/gm,  '').split('').sort().reverse();

  // find letters and replace them with those in array, one by one

  return str.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/gm,  () => {
    return letters.pop();
  });
}

console.log(Reverser('z<*zj')); // j<*zz
console.log(Reverser('xy-a=cb')); // ab-c=xy
```